# Updating a nested property with a different value if found, else add it

Tags: javascript

Assume I have an target object like the following:

```
{
  "info": {
    "name": "Tito",
    "email": "tito@foo.com",
    "company": "FOOBAR INC."
  }
}
```

I'd like to patch/update the target above object with the following object:

```
{
  "info": {
    "email": "tito@foobar.com",
    "company": "Foobar Inc.",
    "state": "CA"
  }
}
```

Thus ending with the following:

```
{
  "info": {
    "name": "Tito",
    "email": "tito@foobar.com",
    "company": "Foobar Inc.",
    "state": "CA"
  }
}
```

What is the easiest way to update if found, add if not found (taking into account that the properties might be nested). Is there an easy way to do this?

I have tried the following so far, though only works with first-level properties:

```
module.exports.mergeObjects = function (obj1, obj2) {
  var obj3 = {};
  for (var attrname1 in obj1) {
    if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(attrname1)) {
      obj3[attrname1] = obj1[attrname1];
    }
  }
  for (var attrname2 in obj2) {
    if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(attrname2)) {
      obj3[attrname2] = obj2[attrname2];
    }
  }
  return obj3;
};
```

I need to do a deep traverse. In Obj-C I would do that in a snap, but being new to JS, I'm not sure whether I'm trying to do too much.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using jQuery, take a look at `$.extend()`.

Comment: 3R - recursively recursive recursion!

Comment: take a look at `__proto__` or `prototype` in javascript

Comment: @Barmar, make that comment an answer, I'll vote for it :)

Comment: I'm not using jQuery. It's Javascript running on Node.js.

Comment: Then I suggest you look at the source code of `jQuery.extend`. http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/deconstructed/jquery/

Comment: @Mics, no it's "recursively recursive 3R" :-D

Comment: @Barmar, jQuery deconstructed is an awesome resource to see how some functions are implemented. The problem is that it can be quite messy to extract all the dependencies. It ends up being more work than it's worth. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a good candidate (at least it's working for me as I expected, we'll see if I end up finding some limitations):

https://github.com/nrf110/deepmerge/blob/master/index.js

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can define all of the possible properties that these objects might be comparing then you might just make that into a class (well the javascript approximation). After that then you can compare the prototype as mentioned to test if they are the same type of object and then you could define a comparison function which will correctly compare any two objects of that class. If the class has members of other definable classes then you can write comparison functions for those classes and call those in the upper level comparison function. This would be similar to a more traditional object oriented approach.

To create a completely generic method the inheritance chains that were mentioned probably would be a good place to start. Object.create() in particular would probably be helpful.

Here is a tutorial on object oriented javascript. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript
and for Object.create
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Answer (score 0):

The quickest merger I could come up with is the following:

```
var mergeObjects = function (original, merging) {
    var merger = function (target, merging) {
        for (var member in merging) {
            if (merging.hasOwnProperty(member)) {
                if (typeof merging[member] === "object") {
                    if (!target[member]) {
                        target[member] = {};
                    }
                    merger(target[member], merging[member]);
                } else {
                    target[member] = merging[member];
                }    
            }
        }
        return target;
    }
    return merger(merger({},original), merging);
};
```

I only ran it through a few tests so make sure to test it.

Called with:

```
mergeObjects(obj1, obj2);
// Where obj1 is the original object
// And obj2 is the object being merged with obj1
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MJvWD/)

Comment: Your solution works fine too. Awesome. I'm trying to catch up with Javascript's good vs. bad parts, so I'm not sure whether your code should be testing against these nasty raw edges that Javascript contains. The deepmerge implementation I mentioned above seems to be testing for some of those. What do you think?

Comment: @titusmagnus, I think you should go with whatever your heart desires :-D. Just remember to never use code until you understand it.